# Unable to send PHP data to table from html select function. Select data fill from database

Tags: php

I am trying to create forms that allow the user to select specific information pulled from a customer table. Once selected, that information is is added to a client table. The information is pulling with no problem and I can select the pertinent information, but when I submit, it is not storing in the client table (sold_property). All information other than the select button is loading into the data table. I have spent hours searching for a solution and would really appreciate some help. This is my first large PHP driven project. Thank you.

```
enter code here: HTML5 <section id="Main">
<div id="main"> 
    <center><h2>Create Sold Property</h2></center>
    <form name="myform" action="includes/property.php" method="post">       

    <label for="vin_id">Vin ID:</label> <select id="vin_id" type="text"  name="vin_id"><?php include "includes/vin_id.php";?></select><br><br>
    <label for="name">Customer Name:</label><select id="customer_name" type="text" name="customer_name"><?php include "includes/customername.php";?></select><br><br>
    <label for="sale_price">Sale Price:</label>   <input type="text" name="sale_price" placeholder="Sale Price" required><br><br>
    <label for="down_payment">Down Payment:</label> <input type="text" name="down_payment" placeholder="Down Payment" required><br><br>
    <label for="loan_amount">Loan Amount:</label>   <input type="text" name="loan_amount"   placeholder="Loan Amount" required><br><br>
    <label for="interest_rate">Interest Rate:</label>   <input type="text" name="interest_rate" placeholder="Interest Rate" required><br><br>
    <label for="terms">Terms:</label> <input type="text" name="terms" placeholder="Terms of the Sale" required><!--Terms should be a select button to avoid confusion--><br><br>
    <label for="total_payments">Total Number of Payments:</label>   <input type="text" name="total_payments"   placeholder="Total Number of Payments" required ><br><br>
    <label for="payment_amount">Payment Amount:</label>   <input type="phone" name="payment_amount" placeholder="Payment Amount" required><br><br>
    <label for="purchase_date">Purchase Date:</label> <input type="datetime-local" name="purchase_date" required><br><br>
    <label for="first_payment_date">First Payment Due Date:</label> <input type="date" name="first_payment_date"   placeholder="First Payment Due" required ><br><br>
    <label for="amort_sched">Amortization Schedule:</label> <input type="text" name="amort_sched"  placeholder="Amortization Schedule" required><br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="register" id="button" value="Submit"/>
                    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset"/>
```

```
<?php 
include "../php/images.php"; 


//escape variables for security
$vin_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vin_id']);
$customer_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['customer_name']);

$sale_price = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['sale_price']);
$down_payment = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['down_payment']);
$loan_amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['loan_amount']);
$terms = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['terms']);
$total_payments = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['total_payments']);
$payment_amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['payment_amount']);
$purchase_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['purchase_date']);
$first_payment_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first_payment_date']);
$amort_sched = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['amort_sched']);



$sql="INSERT into sold_property (vin_id, customer_name, sale_price, down_payment, loan_amount, terms, total_payments, payment_amount, purchase_date, first_payment_date, amort_sched) 
VALUES ('$vin_id','$customer_name', '$sale_price', '$down_payment', '$loan_amount', '$terms', '$total_payments', '$payment_amount',
 '$purchase_date', '$first_payment_date', '$amort_sched')"; 

    if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        die('Error:' .mysqli_error($con));
    } echo "1 record added";

    mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

Comment: So you are getting the values of every element, except for the 2 selects -> `name="vin_id"` & `name="customer_name"`? Could you show your output from `<?php include "includes/vin_id.php";?>` and `<?php include "includes/customername.php";?>`. Also, you have invalid syntax for you selects -> `<select id="vin_id" type="text"  name="vin_id">` & `<select id="customer_name" type="text" name="customer_name">`. A `<select>` is not a `type="text"`.

Comment: Thank you Sean, I don't get any errors thrown, the data gathered all goes to the data table as requested except for the information selected from the <select> boxes. I will try the data type suggestion and see what happens. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a var_dump() of $_POST and $con, to be sure you actually receive informations for the form, and have a valid MySQL connection.

Answer (score 0):

Adding and retrieving information from a drop down.  This worked perfectly. Thanks for the help guys. Trial and error is still the best lesson.

html:

```
<label for="item">Item:</label> <select name="item"><?php include 'includes/item.php';?></select>

includes/item.php:

<?php 
 include "includes/selectconn.php"; //includes for database access/connection
 $query = "SELECT item FROM table"; 
 $result = $mysqli->query($query);  

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    echo '<option value="'.$row["item"].'">'.$row["item"].'</option>'; //the option   value "'.$row['item'].'" - is the data that will be added to your table from the drop down list.
```

?>